# How to convert a scanned text from PDF to Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, pdf-reader

I have a scanned text in PDF format but it is in Arabic how to convert it into a Word file so that the text remains in Arabic.

Comment: If you have the newest Word 2019, you can directly open the PDF in word. It should load it in as one picture. If you want to be able to edit the text too, you will need an expensive program that can do image to text OCR.

Comment: If you have Adobe Acrobat you save a PDF as a Word document.  However, if the scanned document is just an image of a scanned page, what will be created is a Word document with the same image.

Comment: i need to install Microsoft office 2019

Comment: I need a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are specific about Word format use Adobe Acrobat or Foxit software. IF you are looking for a software where you can search and copy text from scanned files, I would recommend having a look at [OCRvision](https://www.OCRvision.com). We support Arabic language as well. Basically it will create a searchable PDF, which can be searched, copied like a word document.

PS: I work for OCRvision.